# Problems reading a CSV file into R with incomplete quotes, commas in character strings and unusual characters

Tags: r, string, csv

I'm trying to read in a large CSV file to R. The file is available at https://github.com/AidData-WM/public_datasets/releases/download/v3.0/AidDataCore_ResearchRelease_Level1_v3.0.zip and the READ ME states that encoding is UTF-8 and there should be 1,561,039 rows and 68 columns. I have tried several different ways to read in the data, but cannot get the full dataset to be read in. I think some problems might arise because: (i) there are incomplete quotations inside character strings, (ii) there are commas inside character strings and `sep=","` (so I can't use `quote=""` to deal with the quotations issue), and (iii) there are unusual characters such as arrows.

Here are my various attempts to read the data and the resulting warnings:

```
aid <- read.csv("AidDataCoreFull_ResearchRelease_Level1_v3.0.csv"),header=T, encoding="UTF-8")
> dim(aid)
[1] 9960   68
```

Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string

```
aid <- read.table("AidDataCoreFull_ResearchRelease_Level1_v3.0.csv"),header=T,sep=",",encoding="UTF-8")
> dim(aid)
[1] 9960   68
```

Warning messages:
1: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
2: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns

```
aid <- read.csv("AidDataCoreFull_ResearchRelease_Level1_v3.0.csv"),header=F,skip=1,quote="",encoding="UTF-8")
> dim(aid)
[1] 10956    72
```

No warning message this time, but no where near the full rows read in and now too many columns.

```
tx <- readLines("AidDataCoreFull_ResearchRelease_Level1_v3.0.csv",encoding="utf-8",skipNul=T)
> length(tx)
[1] 9961
```

Warning message:
In readLines("AidDataCoreFull_ResearchRelease_Level1_v3.0.csv",  :
  incomplete final line found on 'AidDataCoreFull_ResearchRelease_Level1_v3.0.csv'

I can't find a combination of commands that reads in the full CSV, and I can't open it in excel in order to view and try to tidy up the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using readr::read_csv. It's a little bit easier to debug than base read.csv and it'll tell you where things went wrong with ```problems(aid)```.

(Reference: http://readr.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: Thanks! That function is so much more helpful, and has actually read the whole dataset in while detailing the problems found, that's all I need - brilliant!